# Does every set of any three vertices of a cube determine a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I recently came across this in my textbook:

> Any three vertices of a cube determine a right triangle.  Is this a true statment?

My initial thought was that is was, but the answers say otherwise.  I cannot, however, come up with a counterexample.

What three vertices of a cube **don't** determine a right triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are standing at a corner. Consider the three corners closest to you.

These three corners determine a triangle, all of whose sides are face diagonals. So all these sides have equal length, the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: That is brilliant.  It seems that there still should be right angles where lines from perpendicular planes meet, though, but that can't be...

Comment: You are right about where three perpendicular planes meet, but this triangle kind of slices across. All triangles without a right angle arise in this way. There are some slightly weird ones. For example, let $A$ be a vertex, let $B$ be a neighbouring vertex, and let $C$ be the corner *furthest* from $B$. Then $\triangle ABC$ has sides $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ so by the converse of the Pythagorean Theorem it has a right angle at $A$.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw the cube so that it looks like a hexagon.

Comment: If you're referring to a drawing of a cube with the illusion of 3 dimensions, I have tried this.  Otherwise, I haven't the slightest idea how to make a cube look like a hexagon.  >.>

Comment: Then draw it like you did before, and then find a non-right triangle on this projection.

Comment: I have looked, and had others look.  This question is my "I give up; where is it?" :\

Comment: Connect every second vertex of this hexagon. What happens?

Comment: Ah, there it is! That is an interesting way to look at it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Three that involve no edges from the cube. If the vertices are the standard ones for the unit cube, then, $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, and $(1,1,0)$ will do.